# deleting filters in tc

Tags: linux, networking, routing, traffic-shaping, tc

I have added a filter in tc as follows:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip handle 6 fw flowid 1:6
```

This should be sending packets marked by iptables with '--set-mark 6' to class 1:6. The problem is, I can't figure out how to later delete this filter. Replacing 'add' with 'delete' doesn't work, I get a 'RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory' error message. I've tried a number of other combinations to delete it, but none seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try 'del' instead of 'delete'?

Comment: @Dan Yup, same result

Answer (score 5):

The thing is when you issue filter add w/o exact *preference/priority* number, it gets assigned automatically, you can see it with:

`tc filter show dev eth0`

and it would get deleted as easy as

`tc filter del dev eth0 prio nUmErIc`

If you need more control you have to specify 'prio' exactly:

`tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 handle 6 fw flowid 1:6`

In this way it's up to either you repeat all the gory details to remove filter or just use the former way.

Answer (score 0):

from the source [/net/sched/cls_api.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/sched/cls_api.c#L2223) it follows
that one workaround is to use `prio != 0`

```
    if (prio == 0 && (protocol || t->tcm_handle || tca[TCA_KIND])) {
    NL_SET_ERR_MSG(extack, "Cannot flush filters with protocol, handle or kind set");
    return -ENOENT;
}
```